# How to solve Javascript template not returning correct value issue in Django,?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I created some values with various operations in my views. Since I am using `USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True` in the project, I am going through some operations (otherwise the charts don't work), when I print the final value in the terminal, the value appears correctly.

But in the template, it does not take the full value of the integer in javascript, it shows incomplete.

For example,

in views terminal:

```
print(t1credit) --> 2241825 (Correct)
```

in template:

```
window.alert( ({{ t1credit }}) ) --> 2  (not correct)
```

How can I solve it?

**views.py**

```
top_1_country = Customer.objects.values(
            'country__country_name'
        ).annotate(Count('country'),
                   Sum('credit_limit')).order_by('-country__count')[:1]
        t1country = ""
        t1count = 0
        t1credit = 0
        counter = 0
        for top in top_1_country:
            for q,w in top.items():
                if counter == 0:
                    t1country = w
                elif counter == 1:
                    t1count = w
                else:
                    t1credit = w
                counter += 1
        sep = '.'
        t1credit = str(t1credit)
        t1credit = t1credit.split(sep, 1)[0]
        t1credit = t1credit.replace(',', '')
        t1credit = int(t1credit)
```

Comment: Did you look at the source code in the browser? Press Ctrl+U. What does `window.alert( ({{ t1credit }}) )` end up as?

Comment: it shows     window.alert( (2,241,825) ) then why it displays different?

Comment: You should keep it as string - without using `int()` - and you should use `" "` in JavaScript to inform JavaScript  that it has to treat it as string. `window.alert( "{{ t1credit }}" )` When you put without `""` then you get `window.alert( (2,241,825) )` which is treated as three arguments `window.alert( 2,  241,  825 )` because `,` is used in JavaScript as separator for aguments in function - and adding `( )` can't change it..

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your comment. I figure it out now. I used `x_1 = parseInt((String("{{ t3credit }}").replace(',', '')).replace('.', ''))` and it works. If you want you can send  your comment as answer.